# react history replace disallow back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I know it's impossible technically to disable user to click the back button of the browser, but it doesn't make sense some time in our app we allow that kind of operation.

For example in my job application app, after you apply you go to next page,

```
this.props.applyJob({
      id: this.state.selectedAd_Id,
      applicant_id
    }).then(response => {
      if(response.value.status === 200){
        const { id } = response.value.data.result
        this.props.history.replace(`/job/applied/${id}`)
      }
    })

but user still can go to the previous page which doesn't make sense, how to handle that?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a onunload function of some sort.  If the user clicks the button that you want them to click you would have to set a variable so they dont get the warning message.

```
    var showAlert= 1; // this is set to it will show warning when leaving the page

    // if they click your next button add this to a function
    // showAlert =0;

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if (showAlert == 1)
  return 'Please use the Next and Previous buttons and not the browser back buttons to ensure your date is saved.';
};
```

Comment: this is to hack to browser, not recommended